# best way to whittle down features in a classification machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have 66 features which i'm using to create a classifcation machine learning model in python. However, just to prevent issues like overfitting, I was wondering what the best way to reduce the number of fetures would be. I have read about PCA, but am not sure whether any good methodology exists to reduce features, and whether any tools exist in sklearn to  help facilitate this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should then maybe do is reading through the documentation of scikit-learn's [feature selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) methods.

Every method has its perks and peeves, and which one is best (if there is even one) depends on the specific use-case.

That being said, the methods offered in scikit-learn are by no means exhaustive. But discussing different choices and elaborating on an appropriate method is maybe better asked on platforms like [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or similar.